# Want to call a non-static Interface method in a static method. How?

Tags: java

I facing a real hard problem in my code snippet.

I want to  learn how to use Interface in Java the correct way.

So for this I have my Application-Class...

```
package inversionUsage;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String standard = "Standard version!";

        if (FeatureDecisions.checkEnabledFeatures("new-feature1")) {
            System.out.println("Implement new feature...");
        }else {
            System.out.println(standard);
        }

    }

}
```

Then I made a Interface...

```
package inversionUsage;

public interface AppConfiguration {

    boolean isEnabled(String searchFeature);

}
```

I want to use the Interface in another class:

```
package inversionUsage;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class FeatureDecisions implements AppConfiguration{

    public String [] enabledFeatures;
    public String [] _implNewFeature = fetchFeatureTogglesFromSomehere();

    public static boolean checkEnabledFeatures(String searchFeature) {
        return isEnabled(searchFeature);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(String searchFeature) {

        if (Arrays.asList(_implNewFeature).contains(searchFeature)) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    private String [] fetchFeatureTogglesFromSomehere() {
        // TODO get the CONFIG from somewhere
        enabledFeatures = new String [2];
        enabledFeatures[0] = "new-feature1";
        enabledFeatures[1] = "new-feature2";
        return enabledFeatures;
    }

}
```

So the workflow is:
1. I start the Application
2. Main method checks the enabled features via FeatureDecisions.java
3. In Feature Decisions i implemented the Interface

I getting the error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method isEnabled(String) from the type FeatureDecisions
```

May Someone can help me out?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to use an instance method is to have an instance on which to call it. Your `checkEnabledFeatures` is static, so it doesn't receive an instance you can use (as `this`). To use an instance method, it would need to create an instance. But obviously that's not what you want here.

Java's `interface` construct is for defining the interface that *instances* implement. Java doesn't have the concept of a "static interface" that a class must implement. On the rare occasions when that's needed, it's usually implemented using reflection (perhaps with a class-level annotation to indicate that the class has the necessary feature).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to instantiate the FeatureDecisions class.

```
public static boolean checkEnabledFeatures(String searchFeature) {
    return new FeatureDecisions().isEnabled(searchFeature);
}
```

or make all members static.

Additional info: There are [frameworks like togglz](https://www.togglz.org/) that do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that. The closest can get is to use the singleton pattern (though lots of people - myself included - would discourage it).

```
public enum FeatureDecisions implements AppConfiguration
{
    INSTANCE;

    public String [] enabledFeatures;
    public String [] _implNewFeature = fetchFeatureTogglesFromSomehere();

    public boolean checkEnabledFeatures(String searchFeature) {
        return isEnabled(searchFeature);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(String searchFeature) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Your call would then change from:

```
FeatureDecisions.checkEnabledFeatures(...)
```

to

```
FeatureDecisions.INSTANCE.checkEnabledFeatures(...)
```

---

It's also worth noting that `checkEnabledFeatures` doesn't actually do anything besides defer to `isEnabled`. You could scrap the former and just call the latter directly.